# Replacing multiple strings from a databsae column with distinct replacements

Tags: sql, regex, hive, regexp-replace

I have a hive table as below:

```
+----+---------------+-------------+
| id | name          | partnership |
+----+---------------+-------------+
| 1  | sachin sourav | first       |
| 2  | sachin sehwag | first       |
| 3  | sourav sehwag | first       |
| 4  | sachin_sourav | first       |
+----+---------------+-------------+
```

In this table I need to replace strings such as "sachin" with "ST" and "Sourav" with "SG". I am using following query, but it is not solving the purpose.

Query:

```
select 
    *,
    case
       when name regexp('\\bsachin\\b') 
          then regexp_replace(name,'sachin','ST')
       when name regexp('\\bsourav\\b') 
          then regexp_replace(name,'sourav','SG')
       else name
    end as newName
from sample1;
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | name          | partnership | newname       |
+----+---------------+-------------+---------------+
| 4  | sachin_sourav | first       | sachin_sourav |
| 3  | sourav sehwag | first       | SG sehwag     |
| 2  | sachin sehwag | first       | ST sehwag     |
| 1  | sachin sourav | first       | ST sourav     |
+----+---------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Problem: My intention is, when id = 1, the newName column should bring value as "ST SG". I mean it should replace both strings.

Comment: Supply a data sample varied enough to reflect the logic you want to apply. Include also the required results (and **not** the results your are currently getting with your attempts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the replaces:

```
select s.*,                                             
       replace(replace(s.name, 'sachin', 'ST'), 'sourav', 'SG') as newName
from sample1 s;
```

You don't need regular expressions, so just use `replace()`.

Comment: When id=4, I have the name as "sachin_sourav", that should not be changed. Only full words needs to be replaced. I tried nested regexp_replace, it it working. May I dont need case..when statement.

Comment: Is "sachin" only at the start of the string and will there always be a single space following?  If so, replace the inner replace() with `replace(s.name, 'sachin ', 'ST ')` to search for and preserve the space.